# How to enable/disable a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the click of UIBarButtonItems?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uipangesturerecognizer

I am currently having trouble on disabling/enabling a pan gesture with the click of a UIBarButtonItem. Currently I understand the simple code for it, but for some reason the code is not being read. This is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)saveRep {



buttonCount ++;
if (buttonCount > 0) {

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];


    for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {        

        panner.enabled=NO;


    }
}
}
- (IBAction)editButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)editRep {



buttonCount ++;
if (buttonCount > 0) {

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];
    _draggedView = panner.view;

    for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {
        panner.enabled = YES;

    }

}
}
```

When I click on the saveButton, I would like for the panner to be disabled, which I have set up with the `panner.enabled=NO;` However, this code is not working! After I press the save button the panner is still enabled and working.

I would then like to click the editButton to enable the panner again, which I have tried to do with the `panner.enable=YES;`

Originally I am adding this  pan gesture recognizer to a UIButton that I am creating when I click on my addRepButton. Here is my entire set of code for reference:

```
@implementation FieldGoalChartViewController
{

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];


}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];

CGRect buttonRect = self.buttonField.frame;


CGPoint point = [aTouch locationInView:self.buttonField.superview];



if (!CGRectContainsPoint(buttonRect, point)) {
        _buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        _draggedView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {
        _buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    }

}


}

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ) {
    gesture.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;


    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Would you like to delete the selected rep(s)?"
                                  message:nil
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* deleteButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                                   {
                                       for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {
                                           if ([[UIColor colorWithCGColor:_buttonField.layer.borderColor] isEqual:[UIColor whiteColor]]) {

                                               [_buttonField removeFromSuperview];

                                           }
                                       }

                                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                }];
    UIAlertAction* cancelButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {






                                   [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                               }];

    [alert addAction:deleteButton];
    [alert addAction:cancelButton];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}




- (void)panWasRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {
{

    panner.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;


   _draggedView = panner.view;

    CGPoint offset = [panner translationInView:_draggedView.superview];
    CGPoint center = _draggedView.center;
    _draggedView.center = CGPointMake(center.x + offset.x, center.y + offset.y);


    _draggedView.layer.masksToBounds =YES;
    _buttonField.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;


    // Reset translation to zero so on the next `panWasRecognized:` message, the
    // translation will just be the additional movement of the touch since now.
    [panner setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:_draggedView.superview];

}

}

-(void)buttonTouched:(UIButton*)sender forEvent:(id)tap {
NSSet *touches = [tap allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
touch.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor
                                ].CGColor;
}


-(void)doubleTapped:(UIButton*)sender forEvent:(id)twoTaps {
NSSet *touches = [twoTaps allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
touch.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

}
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)saveRep {



buttonCount ++;
if (buttonCount > 0) {

    for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];


        panner.enabled=NO;


    }
}
}
- (IBAction)editButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)editRep {



buttonCount ++;
if (buttonCount > 0) {

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];
    _draggedView = panner.view;

    for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {
        panner.enabled = YES;

    }

}
}


- (IBAction)addRepButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)newRep {

self.labelCounter++;

buttonCount ++;
if (buttonCount > 0 )
{

    _buttonField = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 300, 28, 28)];
    [_buttonField setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.labelCounter]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_buttonField setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _buttonField.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    _buttonField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _buttonField.layer.cornerRadius = 14;
    _buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _buttonField.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    _buttonField.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    [_buttonField setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _buttonField.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _buttonField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


    //Pan gesture declared in button
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];
    [_buttonField addGestureRecognizer:panner];

    //Long Press gesture declared in button
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    [self.buttonField addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    //Touch down inside declared in button
    [self.buttonField addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    //Double Tap inside declared in button
    [self.buttonField addTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapped:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];


    [self.view addSubview:(_buttonField)];




}


}







@end
```

I am looking to find out why my UIPanGestureRecognizer is not being enabled/disabled when called upon to do so.

Comment: the pan gesture recognizer needs to be added to the view where you want the gesture to work.

Comment: it is added within my "addRepButton" method, or are you referring to something else? please elaborate

Comment: you just want to pan the button? or is it a field that you want to pan?  also, in saveButton and editButton you create new gesture recognizers but don't assign them to anything

Comment: I want to pan the button that I create with the addRepButton method.

So with the saveButton and editButton I would like to disable/enable the pan that I added through my addRepButton method

Comment: @MikeM would you happen to know how I should go about that?

Comment: you are creating a new pan gesture in saveButton and editButton.  So even if you were able to pan, you wouldn't be able to  stop it.  The pan may also not work because UIButtoin has its own set of gestures.  you could replace the UIButton with a UIView, and also add a tap gesture for button functionality